# Rails RABL if else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I'm using RABL in a Rails app to access data via REST.  It's working except for the if statement.

I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `matitem_id'
```

This is my show.json.rabl code:

```
object @expense
attributes :id, :unitcost, :quantity, :markup, :exp_date, :created_at, :description, :pcard, :invoice

child :employee do
  attributes :id, :maxname
end

child :vendor do
  attributes :id, :vendor_name
end

if matitem_id != nil
  child :matitem do |matitem|
    attributes :id, :itemnum
  end
end
```

UPDATE1

I also tried

```
if @expense.matitem_id != nil
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working?

Comment: Sorry - I changed the questions and added the error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `matitem_id` is an attribute of the `@expense` object you should reference it in a conditional through the `root_object` helper like this:

```
if root_object.matitem_id
  child :matitem do |matitem|
    attributes :id, :itemnum
  end
end
```

Also, the `!= nil` is probably redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`if :matitem_id != nil`

Is literally comparing the symbol `:matitem_id` to `nil`. This will NEVER be true. What you need to do is compare the ID of the child object. You can pass the object into the block:

```
child :matitem do |matitem|
  if matitem.id != nil
    ...
end
```

Comment: Does your Expense model have `belongs_to :matitem`?